# adding <head> tags to index file breaks express routing

Tags: html, express, angular

I have a completely barebones express app, with an `app.js` with an html rendering engine like this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

I want index.html to host an Angular2 one-page app. In my `./views` directory I have an index.html and an error.html file. My index.html file looks like this:

```
<head></head>
<h1>Home</h1>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

With this set up everything works fine. However, if I add anything to the head section, e.g.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<h1>Home</h1>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

Then rather than `localhost` resolving to index I now get the error page. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid HTML. You can't have `<h1>` or `<my-app>` as sibling to `<head>`. Move the content to a `<body>` tag.

Event though the browser might add `<body>` automatically it's bad practice and Angular doesn't like invalid HTML. Angulars HTML parser is strict and if the provided HTML is not valid it throws an error (for HTML in component templates).

I'm not sure this is the root cause of your problem but I don't think it makes much sense to investigate more before this isn't fixed.

The `<head>` tag might need a `<base href="/">` as first child element (if `APP_BASE_HREF` is not provided).